# java program to draw a line with given start point and angle

Tags: java, indicator, gauge

I was trying to create a gauge with ability for the user to use custom background image and size and everything works. But in some shapes the needle/pointer gets wrongly oriented.

To be more specific, in some cases(pointer starting points can be given by the user) I know the start point of the needle/pointer in the dial gauge. Now the problem is user can choose the maximum/ minimum  angles and max/min values the gauge represents. Can anyone suggest me how i can set the angle so that I can get the correct final points. Here is what i am doing so far

```
  int x1 = centerX, x2 = x1, y1 = centerY, y2 = y1;

  double angle = min_angle + ( 1.0 * ( max_angle - min_angle ) / (1.0 * ( max_val - min_val ) ) ) * ( value - min_val ) ;

  if( max_angle > min_angle  )
     angle = max_angle - angle;
  else 
     angle = min_angle - angle;

  x2 += (int)( Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))*ind_len);
  y2 -= (int)( Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))*ind_len);
```

FYI : This is done in java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did was not entirely wrong, but I did neither see an actual *question*, nor did I read the code closely enough to find the error. Instead, here's a simple gauge implementation.

[image: Gauge Image]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


public class GaugeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        GaugePanel gaugePanel = new GaugePanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(gaugePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel controlPanel = createControlPanel(gaugePanel);
        f.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        f.setSize(600,800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JPanel createControlPanel(final GaugePanel gaugePanel)
    {
        final JSlider minAngleSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);
        final JSlider maxAngleSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);
        final JSlider minValueSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);
        final JSlider maxValueSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);
        final JSlider valueSlider = new JSlider(0, 100, 0);

        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("minAngle"));
        controlPanel.add(minAngleSlider);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("maxAngle"));
        controlPanel.add(maxAngleSlider);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("minValue"));
        controlPanel.add(minValueSlider);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("maxValue"));
        controlPanel.add(maxValueSlider);
        controlPanel.add(new JLabel("value"));
        controlPanel.add(valueSlider);

        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
            {
                double minAngle = minAngleSlider.getValue() / 100.0 * Math.PI * 2;
                double maxAngle = maxAngleSlider.getValue() / 100.0 * Math.PI * 2;
                double minValue = minValueSlider.getValue() / 100.0;
                double maxValue = maxValueSlider.getValue() / 100.0;
                double value = valueSlider.getValue() / 100.0;

                gaugePanel.setAngles(minAngle, maxAngle);
                gaugePanel.setRange(minValue, maxValue);
                gaugePanel.setValue(value);
            }
        };
        minAngleSlider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        maxAngleSlider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        minValueSlider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        maxValueSlider.addChangeListener(changeListener);
        valueSlider.addChangeListener(changeListener);

        minAngleSlider.setValue(50);
        maxAngleSlider.setValue(0);
        minValueSlider.setValue(10);
        maxValueSlider.setValue(90);
        valueSlider.setValue(50);

        return controlPanel;
    }


}

class GaugePanel extends JPanel
{
    private double minAngleRad = 0.0;
    private double maxAngleRad = 0.0;
    private double minValue = 0.0;
    private double maxValue = 0.0;
    private double value = 0.0;

    void setAngles(double minAngleRad, double maxAngleRad)
    {
        this.minAngleRad = minAngleRad;
        this.maxAngleRad = maxAngleRad;
        repaint();
    }

    void setRange(double minValue, double maxValue)
    {
        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        repaint();
    }

    void setValue(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        int ty = 20;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("minAngle "+Math.toDegrees(minAngleRad), 20, ty+=20);
        g.drawString("maxAngle "+Math.toDegrees(maxAngleRad), 20, ty+=20);
        g.drawString("minValue "+minValue, 20, ty+=20);
        g.drawString("maxValue "+maxValue, 20, ty+=20);
        g.drawString("value "+value, 20, ty+=20);


        double alpha = (value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue);
        double angleRad = minAngleRad + alpha * (maxAngleRad - minAngleRad);

        double length = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 3.0;

        double x0 = getWidth() / 2.0;
        double y0 = getHeight() / 2.0;
        double x1 = x0 + Math.cos(angleRad) * length;
        double y1 = y0 - Math.sin(angleRad) * length;

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fill(new Arc2D.Double(
            x0-length, y0-length, 
            length+length, length+length, 
            Math.toDegrees(minAngleRad), 
            Math.toDegrees(maxAngleRad-minAngleRad), 
            Arc2D.PIE));

        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(new Line2D.Double(x0, y0, x1, y1));


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. Will test it and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found where I was going wrong. My code was fine. Mistake was in the inputs. I was giving inputs in clockwise and the code wants it in counter clockwise